# Double operation return infinite

Tags: c#

I'm trying get a percentage change between double that can be positive or negative then increment change but a simple double operation in code return infinite but I'm not sure why I can't add those 2 doubles.

```
Cchange = CalculateChangePercent(currenttHigh.BidHigh, ohlc.BidHigh);
Hchange = Cchange + Hchange;
Debug.WriteLine(timeSpan + " Trace operation : " + Cchange + " -->  " + Hchange) ;


public double CalculateChangePercent(double previous, double current)
  {
      var change = Math.Abs(current) - Math.Abs( previous);
      return (double)change / previous;
  }
```

console output :

> D1 Trace operation : -0,0500557519599624 -->  ∞
>   D1 Trace operation : -0,0463130234849731 -->  ∞
>   D1 Trace operation : -0,0438149899300724 -->  ∞
>   D1 Trace operation : -0,0457166071690971 -->  ∞

Comment: `Hchange = Cchange + Hchange;` <-- what is the initial value of `hChange` ? Can you provide sample input ?

Comment: 1d / 0d = ∞. Are you dividing by 0?

Comment: look in log output its the first number

Comment: Indeed, it would be easier to help you with a [mcve].

Comment: the first calculation work well since i have number  -0,0500557519599624 but when i addition first and second result is  infinit

Comment: its in loop so adding cchange to next cchange does the bug

Comment: `currenttHigh.BidHigh` is zero.

Comment: @damienmousel in the logs, it shows that `Hchange` first value is already `∞`. That's why I'm asking the initial value

Comment: To me, the method `CalculateChangePercent` is not the cause, and **there is no** division by 0 (at least not in the shown code). Otherwise, the console logs would have shown something like `D1 Trace operation : ∞ --> ∞`

Comment: first calcul to me is -0,0500557519599624 + 0 = infinite  , it not make sence

Comment: Maybe would be nice to get more code to read, for having a better context.

Comment: Just a suggestion: [http://scotthannen.org/blog/2019/09/02/improve-stack-overflow-questions-unit-tests.html](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2019/09/02/improve-stack-overflow-questions-unit-tests.html). If you wrote this as a unit test the question would be encapsulated, showing the inputs and expected results. Then it would be super easy for someone to understand what values you are passing to the function, what you expect, and to work with it to help you get the result you expect.

Comment: @ScottHannen nice reading, thank you for having written it